# send wifi credentials to ESP32 via web Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, esp32, web-bluetooth

Im trying to send wifi credentials to esp32 BLE device using web bluetooth.
I'm getting the error `Received invalid JSON` for every combination I've tried so far. Right now the code is simple and goes:

```
const connectToDeviceAndSubscribeToUpdates = async () => {
    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        // filers: ["ESP32-E89F6DD0DF34"],
        acceptAllDevices: true,
        optionalServices: ["0000aaaa-ead2-11e7-80c1-9a214cf093ae"],
    });

    let server = await device.gatt.connect();
    const service = await server.getPrimaryService(
        "0000aaaa-ead2-11e7-80c1-9a214cf093ae"
    );

    let characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(
        "00005555-ead2-11e7-80c1-9a214cf093ae"
    );
    console.log(characteristic);

    var thing = await characteristic.readValue();
    var encoder = new TextEncoderStream();
    let data = { ssidPrim: "", pwPrim: "", ssidSec: "", pwSec: "" };
    await characteristic.writeValueWithoutResponse(
        encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(data))
    );
    console.log(response);
};

document.getElementById("connect").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    connectToDeviceAndSubscribeToUpdates();
});
```

the `JSON` `let data = { ssidPrim: "", pwPrim: "", ssidSec: "", pwSec: "" };` has been modified to all shapes for example `{ssid:'',pass:''}` `{ssid:'',password:''}` `{ssid:'',passwd:''}`  `{information:[{ssidPrim:'',passPrim:''}]}` etc. (the empty quotes were filled).

Also I've tried to send it with the methods `writeValue` 'writeValueWithResponse`and`writeValueWithoutResponse` all the same results.

I've read a lot of tutorials but moste of them in C, C++ and I could translate the information into JavaScript.

Right now I'll try any ideas.

The ESP module is Olimex ESP32-WROOM-32F.

I'm using this function in windows powershell to read from the device

```
function read-com {
 $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM8,115200,None,8,one
 $port.Open()
 do {
 $line = $port.ReadLine()
 Write-Host $line 
 } while ($port.IsOpen)
 }
```

Theese are the information from connecting using the above funtion to sending information via web-bluetooth

```
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
load:0x40078000,len:13836
load:0x40080400,len:3608
entry 0x400805f0
Build: Feb 22 2023 22:32:28
Read from preferences:
primary SSID: hhhh password: hhhh
secondary SSID: eeee password: tttttttt
BLE advertising using ESP32-E89F6DD0DF34
Start scanning for networks
Found AP: UPC1690653 RSSI: -42
Found AP: UPC5088637 RSSI: -71
Found AP: Wi-Free #InternetUPCNajszybszy RSSI: -71
Found AP: UPC1690653_EXT RSSI: -73
Found AP: UPC3006601 RSSI: -77
Found AP: Wi-Free #InternetUPCNajszybszy RSSI: -77
Found AP: UPC244036972 RSSI: -83
Found AP: Wi-Free #InternetUPCNajszybszy RSSI: -85
Found AP: UPC4415581 RSSI: -85
Found AP: UPCA1C5DBA RSSI: -86
Found AP: NETIASPOT-72E0C0 RSSI: -86
Found AP: Wi-Free #InternetUPCNajszybszy RSSI: -87
Found AP: UPC1369909 RSSI: -88
Found AP: UPC1176318 RSSI: -90
Found AP: Apartamentowiec Bonczyka_25 RSSI: -91
Found AP: Wi-Free #InternetUPCNajszybszy RSSI: -91
Found AP: [air purifier]_E30AJT1003236X RSSI: -95
Found AP: Wi-Free #InternetUPCNajszybszy RSSI: -95
Found AP: UPC245739629 RSSI: -95
Found AP: UPC5562094 RSSI: -97
Found AP: Wi-Free #InternetUPCNajszybszy RSSI: -97
Could not find any AP


##################################
Internal Total heap 258752, internal Free Heap 151220
SPIRam Total heap 0, SPIRam Free Heap 0
ChipRevision 3, Cpu Freq 240, SDK Version v4.4.3
Flash Size 4194304, Flash Speed 80000000
##################################


BLE client connected
BLE onRead request
Stored settings: {"ssidPrim":"hhhh","pwPrim":"hhhh","ssidSec":"eeee","pwSec":"tttttttt"}
BLE client disconnected
BLE client connected
BLE onRead request
Stored settings: {"ssidPrim":"hhhh","pwPrim":"hhhh","ssidSec":"eeee","pwSec":"tttttttt"}
Received over BLE: {"information":{"ssidPrim":"UPC1690653","pwPrim":"******"}}
Received invalid JSON
```

Comment: What is reporting the "received invalid JSON" error? Is it the ESP32? If it is, the immediate question is exactly what did it receive?

Comment: Could be an encoder problem. Firstly, are sure you want to use streaming version of Encoding API? Because subsequent code is using variable `encoder` as it was initialized as standard `TextEncoder` (`TextEncoderStream` interface doesn't have `encode` method). Secondly, mentioned write methods in Bluetooth API expect `ArrayBuffer` as parameter, while encoders in Encoding API are using `Uint8Array` typed arrays. You might need to pass raw buffer into it.

Comment: @romkey is the esp32 that's giving the error

Comment: @adam then it would be more helpful to share the JSON string that the ESP32 receives and fails to decode, and to share the code that receives it and processes it.

Comment: @romkey The whole code is included, the JSON has been changed and tested with multiple combinations like in examples `{ ssid: "validssid",password:'validpassword' }` and the code that sends the value is `await characteristic.writeValueWithoutResponse(
        encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(data))
    );`

Comment: @adam Have you tried my suggestion? Just use standard encoder instead of streaming one (`var encoder = new TextEncoder();`), and then pass raw buffer into method `writeValueWithoutResponse` three lines below (`encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(data)).buffer`).

Comment: @adam I don't want to know what's being sent. I want to know what's being *received* - that's what's generating the error. Please post the value that the ESP32 receives and tries to parse. You haven't shared the whole code - you haven't posted the code that's actually reporting the error, from the ESP32.

Comment: @romkey I've added the way I read from the device and all requests answers. This is the way my friend told me to check responses and I dont know if theres more to this. Sorry for the long respons time, wasn't feeling to well lately.